# Physionomie de Pierrot meaning

Tags: meaning, word-usage, translation

In a quote by William James, he describes John D. Rockefeller as:

> Physionomie de Pierrot (not a spear of hair on head or face) flexible, cunning, quakerish...

In this context, what does "Physionomie de Pierrot" mean? Rockefeller had alopecia so I understand the parenthetical, but could someone please explain what the first part means and its origin?

Comment: Have you looked up “physionomie” and “Pierrot”?

Comment: @Jim oh yes, the character Pierrot, the French translations, etc. I'm just looking for a synthesis of the information in the above context.

Comment: "Pierrot" could refer either to a [*Pierrot clown*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierrot) or to [George Arnold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Arnold_(poet)), an American author and poet who used Pierrot as his pen name.

Comment: It's French, not English.

Comment: *Commedia dell'arte* is Italian. I don't really understand the juxtaposition with a French word, but you may be right. Arnold does rather resemble the Rockefellers, both fils et père.

Comment: The meaning is given in the brackets. The clown Pierrot is hairless, as Rockefeller was, apparently.

Comment: *Physionomie* is the French spelling of *physiognomy*. Maybe he chose to use the French word because Pierrot is French (perhaps it was an idiom at the time?).

Comment: @Andrew Leach -- thanks, want to add this in an answer. Also, in the examples of Pierrot I've seen (Google images), he doesn't seem hairless? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierrot#/media/File:Paul_C%C3%A9zanne,_1888,_Mardi_gras_(Pierrot_et_Arlequin),_oil_on_canvas,_102_x_81_cm,_Pushkin_Museum.jpg

Comment: @Barmar Another example: http://www.allaboutclowns.com/pierrot.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the phrase is French, not English.